# Trouble with pygame.time.get_ticks

Tags: python, pygame

I have stated `time=pygame.time.get_ticks`

then when bliting thing to the screen 
I try `window.blit(time, (0,0))`

but where the time is supposed to be it just says `built in function`.
Why is this??

Answer (score 3):

`pygame.time.get_ticks()` give you number not surface to blit on screen.

Seems you forgot `()` in  `time=pygame.time.get_ticks` ->  `time=pygame.time.get_ticks()`

---

With `()` you run function and get result. Without `()` you get reference to function and you can use it as argument in another function

```
def plus(a,b):
    return a+b

def minus(a,b):
    return a-b

def compute(x, y, function_reference):
    return function_reference(x, y)

print compute(10, 7, plus) # 17
print compute(10, 7, minus) # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to furas answer.

Since this function is called get_ticks, you need to do the actual action to get the ticks.
There is one more thing that troubles me, you are trying to blit a integer to the screen, and this is not possible.

What you need to do is create a surface from the string value of the miliseconds, and blit that.